# Is there a way to use 3d graphics in android other than OpenGL (like importing a 3d file)

Tags: android, 3d

I have a 3d object that I created in autodesk 3d max, and I don't want to have to recreate by hand. is there any way to just import it into android?

Comment: does this question help? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/3d-model-viewers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You suffer from the misconception that the file format for 3D objects is somehow tied to the rendering API. You also do not store, or code your objects in some kind of "OpenGL code".

OpenGL doesn't deal with files at all. You read the file using some parser and feed the data to OpenGL.